# How Do I separate Windows 7 Roaming Profiles from Remote Desktop Services Profiles?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop-services, roaming-profile

I have over one hundred users that have Windows 7 roaming profiles on a couple of Windows 2008 R3 servers. I have implemented a GPO for folder redirection for their Home directory (My Documents) and folder redirection for their Music, Downloads, Videos, and Pictures to their respective local Public folders. I also have the users accessing Remote Applications on a 2008 R3 Terminal Server. I have also created a GPO for Remote Desktop Servicess Profiles to be created on the terminal server to separate the Win7 Roaming profiles from the RDS profiles per Microsofts recommendations.
My current nightmare is separating the Windows7 Roaming profiles from the RDS profiles on the terminal server. What's happening is that the remote desktop profiles is duplicating data from the Win7 profiles and attempting to grab Public folder redirection from the Win7 roaming profile GPO. Is there a way to get the two different profiles to work separatly and independently?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Can you link to Microsoft's recommendation, I've never heard that before from them.

If you don't want the RDS user profiles to roam then you'll need to enable Group Policy loopback processing in Replace Mode in the RDS GPO object so that user settings from the RDS GPO are applied rather than user settings from the GPO in the SOM (Scope of Management) of the user.

Comment: Here is the link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742820.aspx See the 2nd paragraph. I will look into the use of loopback processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what most companies do:

1. Set the path to the roaming profile to be used on the Windows 7 machines in each user's Active Directory object ("Profile" tab).
2. Set the path to be used on the terminal servers in a group policy object that is linked to the OU that contains the computer accounts of the terminal servers.

Please see this article for more information on how to configure user profiles with terminal servers and PCs: [User Profile Design: A Primer](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/01/user-profile-design-a-primer/)